# Show N/A in datalabels, when value is null - Highcharts

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I want to show "N/A" in a column chart, when the data is null. 
This is what I am currently trying to do:
http://jsfiddle.net/90amxpc1/1/

```
dataLabels: {
                formatter: function () {
                    if (this.y == null) {
                        return "N/A";
                    }
                    else {
                        return this.y;
                    }
                }
}
```

But, its not working. What I want to achieve is similar to the accepted Answer to this Question: 
[Highcharts: Returning N/A value instead of 0% in data label](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21938691/highcharts-returning-n-a-value-instead-of-0-in-data-label/21939475#21939475)
or this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/v5vJR/3/

I tried modifying it for the column chart, but it doesnt works out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is just different logic for bar (inverted chart) and column chart, example for column:

```
            formatter: function () {
                if (this.y == null) {
                    var chart = this.series.chart,
                        categoryWidth = chart.plotWidth / chart.xAxis[0].categories.length,
                        offset = (this.point.x) * categoryWidth + categoryWidth / 2,
                        text = chart.renderer.text('N/A', -999, -999).add();

                    text.attr({
                        x: chart.plotLeft + offset - text.getBBox().width / 2, //center label
                        y: chart.plotTop + chart.plotHeight - 8 // padding
                    });

                } else {
                    return this.y;
                }
            },
```

Live demo: http://jsfiddle.net/90amxpc1/4/

**Note:**
You may want to store `text` variable to remove that text when hiding series or zooming into the chart.

Comment: this code duplicate texts if the screen is resized. any remedy?

Comment: See my `note` - store variable with labels, for example simple array. Then before rendering new labels, remove old ones. Or update old ones with new position.

Comment: It seems to be broken now on the latest version of high-charts : 5.0.7

Comment: See my comment [here](https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/issues/2899#issuecomment-281036396).